How to Properly Elevate and Protect Outdoor Electrical Boxes in My Yard
I recently discovered two outdoor electrical boxes in my front yard, situated among three very old trees in an area where the previous owner threw mulch. Here are the details:

Box 1: A 2-gang box with only one standard outlet wired up, positioned just barely above the dirt.
Box 2: A covered 1-gang junction box that was half-buried under the earth.

These two boxes are connected via conduit, which I found after digging down a bit. Additionally, there’s a lamp post about 25 feet away that I believe is being fed by the junction box.
EDIT: So I dug a bit deeper and I believe the first outlet box is being fed from the house by gray UF wire through conduit, then there's buried conduit with NM/B white romex connecting it to the junction box, which is then going to the lamp post via gray UF wire.
My Questions:

Elevation: My first thought is to elevate these boxes much higher above the ground.  I was considering mounting them onto a simple 4x4 post. But I definitely don't have enough wire (from the looks of things) to pull them out to do this.

Protection: Given their current state and proximity to the trees, what are the best practices for protecting these boxes from the elements and potential damage (e.g., water, pests, root growth)? Should I use specific types of boxes or covers for better durability and safety?


Thanks in advance for your help Here are some photos and a drawing I made.





It appears that the boxes were wired with NM/B cable, which is interior use only, so you'll have plenty of length when you remove that and replace it with THWN (or other wet-rated) wires, if you want to "do it right." Likewise, is there a GFCI on this circuit in the house? Either a GFCI receptacle with this connected as "load" or a GFCI deadfront or a GFCI Breaker? Actually one cable looks like UF, (gray sheath) another looks like NM/B (white sheath) UF is fine for wet use, but stupid to put in conduit. No need to replace it if it's there, though.

Can use those or new boxes as just junction boxes and add more cable.  Cannot tell exactly the type of cable/wires, but they need to be UF/wet rated type.  Romex/NM-B is not allowed outside.

Is the UF (gray cable) just running out the back of that box with no conduit, actually? Seems like that when I zoom in.

I've edited the post - I dug a bit deeper and I believe the first outlet box is being fed from the house by gray UF wire through conduit, then there's buried conduit with NM/B white romex connecting it to the junction box, which is then going to the lamp post via gray UF wire.

It’s all through conduit @Ecnerwal

For the half-buried junction box, you can replace it with a fully-buried (flush to surface) electrical hand-hole, after addressing any issues with non-wet-rated cables or wires (can't see if that applies to that box)

If you are unfamiliar with these, they are a junction box (despite having no bottom) you don't need a "regular junction box" inside them. As with all outside work, the connectors should be wet-rated as well as the wires-cables being wet-rated.

Thank you - aren’t these for sprinkler systems?

No. Note the text that says "electric" on the cover. They look similar, they are not the same.

Do you have a link where I can buy one?

"Electrical hand-hole" in your search engine of choice. These are usually the smallest ones, the rectangular sort are far bigger and the concrete types are expensive as well as bigger, but handy if they'll be subject to car traffic. These will take the average lawn-mower so long as they are set flush. Otherwise we're getting into spamming.
